Can we pass between sheaves of suitable type and fibre bundles (not ! etale bundles)?
Today I was forced to think about vector bundles (on manifolds), but in the context of a textbook "otherwise" focused on sheaf theory. I'm interested to what extent this really is an "otherwise"; it would simplify arguments and concepts for me if I could pass between the two. Not because vector bundles are inherently confusing, but because if I see something like 'an exact sequence of bundles' or a 'tensor product of bundles' I get worried (especially since my text doesn't define them) but algebraic notions are very easily stated for sheaves.
If $\pi:E\to M$ is a rank $n$-vector bundle, I can get my hands on its sheaf of (continuous) sections $\mathscr{F}$. Because sheaves are in exact correspondence with etale bundles, $\mathscr{F}$ can also be thought of as arising from some etale $\pi':E'\to M$. Sheaf-theoretic operations work better with $E'$ than with $E$, but one unfortunate problem is that $\pi,\pi'$ do not have the same fibres, the same stalks. Thus there is a problem of figuring out whether or not $\pi$ can be associated with a sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ of $\Bbb R$-modules whose stalks at $x\in M$ really are the fibres $E_x=\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$.
There is a related converse problem. In algebraic geometry, a line bundle is just an invertible sheaf - for me, this is very nice and makes good conceptual sense. Here, that would just mean a sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ of $\Bbb R$-modules locally isomorphic with the constant sheaf $\underline{\Bbb R}$. I would be very happy if this could correspond with line bundles, at least for sheaves over manifolds. Ideally, it would be inverse to whatever process occurs in an answer to the second paragraph. I'd also hope that this would extend for vector bundles; I'd just ask for $\mathscr{G}$ to be locally isomorphic with the constant sheaf to $\Bbb R^n$.
More generally, away from differential geometry, I could just ask: can we associate sheaves (of sets, or spaces, or topological groups or something) locally constant to a certain [object] $F$ with fibre bundles with fibre $F$? Again, the etale bundle wouldn't work because the local trivialisations have singleton fibre (... because it's a local isomorphism) rather than fibre $F$, even if the stalks are all isomorphic with $F$.

A rank $r$ vector bundle $E$ can be identified with a sheaf of $C^\infty_X$-modules which is locally isomorphic to $\oplus_{k=1}^rC^\infty_X$. It's not locally isomorphic to $\underline{\mathbb{R}}^r$, those are distinctly different. Likewise, you can associate a sheaf of sections to any fibre bundle. If this sheaf is locally isomorphic to the sheaf of maps to the fibre, then from this I imagine you can obtain the bundle from the sheaf. But I would leave that as an exercise to you - I am not sure.

@QuaereVerum The standard sheaf of smooth sections would give a sheaf with the 'wrong' stalks though, I'm hoping for something with the same stalk i.e. that's basically just a substitute for the bundle

Stalks and fibres aren't the same thing. Stalks capture infinitesimal information, fibers capture pointwise information. The fibre of a vector bundle is obtained as $\pi^{-1}(x)\cong \mathcal{F}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x\mathcal{F}x$, where $\mathfrak{m}x\subset C^\infty{X,x}$ is the maximal ideal of the stalk $C^\infty{X,x}$. That's how you get the fibres from the stalks, not by using a locally constant sheaf.

@QuaereVerum stalks are the fibres of the étale bundle though. My whole point is that in the naive situation the stalks and fibres differ, for a fibre bundle, and it would be nice to reconcile them as is possible in a general but here unsatisfactory way
